# Does a group of infinite abelian rank necessarily have exponential growth?

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory, free-abelian-group

The *abelian rank* of a group $G$ is the maximum $n$ such that $G$ contains an isomorphic copy of $\mathbb{Z}^n$. A group has infinite abelian rank if it contains $\mathbb{Z}^n$ for every $n$.

If $G$ is finitely generated and has infinite abelian rank, does it necessarily have exponential growth? I found [a paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1962-013-02/S0002-9939-1962-0133356-4/S0002-9939-1962-0133356-4.pdf) by James Reid which seems to say that the answer is *yes* in the case that $G$ is abelian and torsion-free (in this case, $G$ can be written as the sum of two free subgroups, and free groups have exponential growth).

On the other hand, if a group had intermediate growth, theoretically that would be enough to encompass $\mathbb{Z}^n$ for any $n$ without necessarily being exponential. But, I am not sure.

Comment: Free groups of rank $k\gt 1$ have exponential growth, but your group is not a sum of free groups (it would necessarily be nonabelian then!) It is a sum of free **abelian** groups.  A  finitely generated group has polynomial growth if and only if it is virtually nilpotent (Gromov's Theorem), so a finitely generated abelian group has polynomial growth (regardless of rank). This is also a theorem of Wolf, who showed f.g. nilpotent groups have polynomial growth.

Comment: The paper says "all groups under consideration are abelian", so when you see "free group", you should understand "free **abelian** group".

Comment: Ah, thank you for the clarification

Comment: (Also, finitely generated abelian groups cannot have infinite rank...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bartholdi and Erschler](https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.5266) have shown that various permutational wreath products $A\wr_X\Gamma$ (where $\Gamma$ is the first Grigorchuk group and $X$ a suitable transitive $\Gamma$-set) have subexponential growth, and this encompasses $A=\mathbf{Z}$. (See e.g. Lemma 5.1 therein — take $A=\mathbf{Z}\times$ something if necessary.)

So a free abelian group of infinite countable rank embeds (actually, as a normal subgroup) into a finitely generated group of intermediate growth.